# Unable to load firefox Add ons in python selenium

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, firefox-addon

I want to Load Zenmate Firefox Addons when selenium webdriver runs
it runs fine when i run without loading any addons ( extensions ) but having problem while adding any addons .
Here is my Code :

```
def __init__(self):   

        self.main_catag_driver = []
        self.declare_xpaths()
        self.main_web_url = "Some_website_url"
        self.path_fire_fox_file = "~/.mozilla/firefox/7rl1aw4c.default/extensions/firefox@zenmate.com.xpi"
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.add_extension(extension=self.path_fire_fox_file)
        time.sleep(5)
        self.driver.get(self.main_web_url)
```

Error when loading Bar :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrap.py", line 73, in <module>
    obj = carandclassic()
  File "scrap.py", line 28, in __init__
    self.driver.add_extension(extension=self.path_fire_fox_file)
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'add_extension'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`add_extension()` is a method on `FirefoxProfile`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/faq.html?highlight=add_extension#how-to-use-firebug-with-firefox), not `WebDriver`:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.add_extension(extension=self.path_fire_fox_file)

self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

Plus, I'm not sure if you really need that `time.sleep(5)` call - try without wasting 5 seconds.

Comment: Amazing, found this after lots of searching, so UNDERRATED.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with [alecxe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771848), it only worked for some of my extensions. I managed to install all of them successfully (from .xpi files) with [`install_addon()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver.install_addon) which is called on already instantiated `webdriver.Firefox`:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='path_to_geckodriver')
# Path to .xpi file needs to be an absolute path. I think it must be a string too.
driver.install_addon(str(Path('extensions/some_extension.xpi').absolute()))

driver.get("about:addons")  # One step closer to see all extensions at glance
```